# JWindow displays blank for a second before showing image

Tags: java, swing, jwindow

I've written a JWindow that serves as a splash screen for my desktop application. The problem I'm having is that after the window becomes visible, it is momentarily blank before displaying the intended image. The blank window remains sometimes between 0.5 seconds and 2 seconds. I would like the content to be fully rendered before the window becomes visible.

I am on MacOS using Java 1.6.

Here is the window immediate after I start it:

[image]

And just half-second later, it shows the image. The image is quite small (about 95kBytes JPG). I know the problem is not the ImageIcon loading, because the constructor is supposed to block until the image is loaded.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JWindow;

public class SplashScreen extends JWindow
{
    public SplashScreen()
    {
        ClassLoader classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
        ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(classLoader.getResource("res/landscape.jpg"));
        while (imageIcon.getImageLoadStatus() != MediaTracker.COMPLETE) {}
        JLabel lbl = new JLabel(imageIcon);
        getContentPane().add(lbl, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        MouseListener mouseListener = new MouseAdapter()
        {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event)
            {
                setVisible(false);
                dispose();
            }
        };

        addMouseListener(mouseListener);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String argv[])
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    SplashScreen ss = new SplashScreen();
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: Added imageIcon.getImageLoadStatus() in loop, but it has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the JDK SplashScreen. The image loads immediately for me.

See [How to Create a Splash Screen](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html).

Comment: When you say "The image loads immediately for me", are you referring to my code, or some other example using the JDK SplashScreen feature?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010, I'm referring to the SplashScreen. It was specially designed to load an image and display the window immediately without loading the entire JVM.

Answer (score 0):

When you construct the ImageIcon you are not loading the image into memory fully at that moment with a blocking operation, your ClassLoader.getResource is only returning you a URL. Reading the [constructor details of ImageIcon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#ImageIcon%28java.net.URL%29) it says that it starts the loading of the URL, but doesn't block. You can check for when the image is done loading by [imageIcon.getImageLoadStatus()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#getImageLoadStatus%28%29) method. When that returns complete, perhaps then set window.setVisible(true).

Comment: I tried that earlier with a loop, but it still didn't work:         `while (imageIcon.getImageLoadStatus() != MediaTracker.COMPLETE) {}`

Comment: Is the drawable space in the JWindow the same pixel size exactly as the image you load? If not, ImageIcon will have to compute a new stretched version of the image and that may take a while. You may be able to get that stretched image cached if you can do a repaint of the ImageIcon before you call setVisible(). Try queuing both actions onto the EDT one after another. You can query for the size of drawing area by obtaining the Insets of the JWindow and subtracting their size.

Comment: I don't set the JWindow size manually. I add the imageIcon into a JLabel and then add the JLabel directly into the JWindow's contentpane. I think the JWindow then sizes itself.

Comment: Oh right it does because you call pack(). I don't know then, sorry. You might be able to see if it is actually spending that time drawing the image with a profiler to see how long the draw operation there takes. That might just be the wait.

Comment: Do you think using a JPanel would help? Adding the JLabel to a JPanel, and then adding the JPanel to the JWindow? I heard that JPanel does "double buffering", whatever that means.

Comment: All Swing does double buffering, it basically means it tells your computer to display a set of graphics once it's done drawing them up, so you don't have to see the drawing actually take place. My current guess is that it takes a while to do the draw. You can test this out if you expand the JWindow a little bit does it make the 500 - 2000ms wait happen again? Another question too, are you constructing this JWindow on the EDT? If not, perhaps there's something goofy where the EDT doesn't see the image loaded into memory yet, but does once some other synchronized block gets hit.

Comment: Regarding "are you constructing this JWindow on the EDT?", I am using `EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() ...` as seen in the main() method. Is that on the EDT?

Comment: Yep, the EDT executes a queue of Runnables, all interaction with Swing should happen on the EDT because Swing classes are not thread safe (this is the practice of thread confinement to deal with non thread safe classes).